# The problem with writing a function in OCaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm trying to write a function that creates a list of powers of a given number.

An example:

```
powList(2,5) = [0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
```

Here is the code I already wrote:

```
    let rec powList (x,n) =
  if n = 0 then []
  else  (let a = let rec power (x, n) =
        if n = 0 then 1 
        else  x * power (x, n-1) in a) ::: powList(x, n-1);;
```

and this is the problem I get

```
    Line 5, characters 31-32:
5 |         else  x * power (x, n-1) in a) ::: powList(x, n-1);;
                                   ^
Error: Syntax error: operator expected.
```

I'm only beginning to code in OCaml so I would be grateful for any help

Comment: The whole `let a` block makes very little sense. Why do you have `a` there at all? And what do you expect its value to be when you're never calling `power` outside its own definition?

Comment: I admit I don't know how to write it. I wanted the value to be the n-th power of the given x. I was able to write a second recursive function 'power' that raises x to the n-th power and then I wanted to include this function into the function that creates the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few generic remarks:

- Don't define (recursive) functions inside recursive functions. Defining helper function in advance will make your code more readable and leave less room for syntax errors. For instance, lifting the definition of `power` outside of `powList` give you

```ml
let rec power x n =
  if n = 0 then 1
  else x * power x (n-1)
  
let rec powList (x,n) =
  if n = 0 then []
  else  ( power ??? :: powList(x, n-1));;
```

- Second, adding an element to a list is done with `::` and not `:::`
- Third, functions are generally curried in idiomatic OCaml code

```
let rec powList x n = ...
```

rather than

```
let rec powList (x,n)
```

because this opens more avenue for composition.

- Fourth, your implementation is inefficient because it recomputes `x^n` at every step without fast exponentation. Consequently, your code ends up computing `n * (n+1)/2` multiplications. Using fast exponentiation would reduce the number of multiplication to O(n log n). However the simpler version of using `x^(n-1)` to computes x yield only n multiplication:

```ml
let pow_list x n =
 let rec pow_list x_power_n n =
   if n = 0 then ...
   else ...
 in
 pow_list ...
```